# file_get_contents() working on localhost but not working on online server

Tags: file-get-contents

```
$result = file_get_contents(ADMIN_URL.'/content/'.$name.'.php');
if($result){
  echo "YES";exit;
}else{
  echo "NO";exit;
}
```

Output is NO,
where ADMIN_URL is "turkjammat.com/demo/administrator/"
and $name is mardumshumari
which makes url in file_get_contents() funciton "turkjammat.com/demo/administrator/content/mardumshumari.php"
and the file is there in above url, this code is working fine in my local xamp server but when i deploying it on my hosting server its not working. plese help some body. Thanks

Comment: You might not have rights to access this resource. Check your logs and post here the errors

Comment: which rights are you taling about?

Comment: Rights to access the resource. Maybe your webserver is blocking those access

Comment: How doi i check whether i have rights for this or not?

Comment: I have call function phpinfo(); an error occured
phpinfo() has been disabled for security reasons in /home/turkjamm/public_html/demo/api/config.php on line 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your hosting server typically does NOT have the same folder hierarchy for user home directories as your local server.

Run php_info() on your hosting server to find out what the correct path is.
Look for DOCUMENT_ROOT in the Environment section.

A simple phpinfo.php file looks like this:

```
<?php
 phpinfo();
?>
```

Comment: It works but there is some php code in my page, and it now randering my php code.

Comment: This is showing in response tab in Network
<?php include(\"..\/..\/api\/config.php\"); include_once(\"..\/model\/functions.php\");?>\r\n<div class=\"row\">\r\n  <div class=\"col-md-12\">\r\n

Comment: Yes. file_get_contents() does what it says: it gets the content. If it is a php file you get the php code. It does NOT execute the code.

Comment: but this executing in my localhost by ADMIN_URL and because ADMIN_URL not working on hosting server i tried DOC_ROOT but php code not executing by DOC_ROOT, what should i do?

Comment: any suggestion please?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
$url = 'your_url.php';    
$opts = array(
    "ssl"=>array(
        "verify_peer"=>false,
        "verify_peer_name"=>false,
    ),
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

$result = file_get_contents( $url , NULL, $context );
echo $result;

?>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: I had the same problem and the problem its related with ssl issue, with ssl on context i solved the problem, he may have the same problem